# SQL Query with join for 2 tables and create new set of columns in result with multiple foreign key in 2nd table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Good day,

I'm trying to get a new list of query result from 2 tables. Here's the sample structure below:

Table1

```
| id | name |
| 11  | Mic  |
| 22  | Jeff |
| 33  | Tom  |
```

while the 2nd table is something like this.
Table2

```
| id | note | customerId1 | customerId2 | customerId3
| 1  | test | 11          | 11          | 22
| 2  | test |             | 33          |
```

So the result should be something like this:

```
| id | note | customer1 | customer2 | customer3 |
| 1  | test | Mic       | Mic       | Tom       |
| 2  | test |           | Tom       |           |
```

What I tried so far is using left join, like this:

```
SELECT Table2.note, Table2.customerId1 as customer1, Table2.customerId2 as customer2,
       Table2.customerId13 as customer3
FROM Table2
    LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.customerId1 = Table1.Id
```

But this isnt' enough is my requirement.

I hope someone can help with this. Thank you.

Comment: you seem to be missing "from table2" in that query

Comment: ah yes, let me update the question. Just a typho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below - **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce865ad2ed8082098579469f59fe3015)**

```
SELECT t.id, note, t1.name as customer1, t2.name as customer2, 
t3.name as customer3
from table2 t
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t.customerId1 = t1.Id
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON t.customerId2 = t2.Id
LEFT JOIN Table1 t3 ON t.customerId2 = t3.Id
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work on my mysql workbench when I want to try this and still returns me an integer id

Comment: @hikhyper, what it returns?

Comment: @hikhyper, I've updated the answer - you can check now

Comment: I'm facing an error that says, 'Error code 1066 not unique table/alies: t1`

Comment: I think I'm having a problem with `t1` and `t` stuff. is there any way to not use them and just use its main table name instead?

Comment: @hikhyper, check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce865ad2ed8082098579469f59fe3015

Comment: Yes, the same works fine. I was also able to fix the error on my query able to run the query, but the problem now is, the name isn't showing. Only blank. It's weird. But in your demo, it's working properly as expected

Comment: haha oh man. it's working now, thank you so much! I missed the t2.Id = and t3.Id on my end hehe I used the same t1.Id across the other joins. hehe Thank you again! and stay safe!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64689668/sql-query-from-getting-subchild-to-child-to-parent-table. Any thoughts for this. I applied what I've learned from your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can `left join` three times:

```
select t2.id, t2.note, t11.name customer1, t12.name customer2, t13.name customer3
from table2 t2
left join table1 t11 on t11.id = t2.customerid1
left join table1 t12 on t12.id = t2.customerid2
left join table1 t13 on t13.id = t2.customerid3
```