# SQL Query from getting SubChild to Child to Parent Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day,

I'm trying to create a custom query for my scenario. Here's the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=979c5665073dcb5781f0f17579496152) I created.

Suppose I have 2 or more parent tables and this table will be consume by a child table.

tblParent1

```
id | name  | age
1  | Lima  | 35
2  | Jenny | 45
```

tblParent2

```
id | name  | age
1  | John | 42
2  | Tess | 41
```

tblParent3

```
id | name  | age
1  | Jeff  | 39
2  | Gyro  | 47
```

Then there's a child table where it consumes these 3 parent tables.

tblChild

```
id | note | tblParent1_key | tblParent2_key | tblParent3_key 
1  | ...  | 1              | 2              | 1           
2  | ...  | 2              | 1              | 1
```

And the child of child table

tblChildOfChild

```
| id | feedback | tblChild_key |
| 1  | anything | 1
```

What I tried so far is using the `left join` between `tblChildOfChild` and `tblChild` but I don't have an idea how can I access the 3 parents of the tblChild. What I need is create a query that has condition in `tblChildOfChild`. What I've done so far is shown below.

```
SELECT t.id, t.feedback, t1.note as note, p1.name as parent1, p2.name as parent2, 
p3.name as parent3
FROM tblChildOfChild t 
LEFT JOIN tblChild t1 ON t.tblChild_key = t1.id
LEFT JOIN tblParent1 p1 ON t1.id = p1.id
LEFT JOIN tblParent2 p2 ON p1.id = p2.id
LEFT JOIN tblParent3 p3 ON p2.id = p3.id
WHERE t.id = 1
```

But I'm getting a different result from what I expected.

The expected result should be:

```
| id | feedback | note | parent1 | parent2 | parent3 |
| 1  | anythin  | ...  | Lima    | Tess    | Jeff    |
```

I'm stuck with this for hours. I hope somebody can help me or give some new knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only thing OP do wrong is `join` the wrong key.

anyway try this first.

```
SELECT t.id, t.feedback, t1.note as note, p1.name as parent1, p2.name as parent2, 
p3.name as parent3
FROM tblChildOfChild t 
LEFT JOIN tblChild t1 ON t.tblChild_key = t1.id
LEFT JOIN tblParent1 p1 ON t1.tblParent1_key = p1.id
LEFT JOIN tblParent2 p2 ON t1.tblParent2_key = p2.id
LEFT JOIN tblParent3 p3 ON t1.tblParent3_key = p3.id
WHERE t.id = 1
```

Comment: Still there's a problem in result. See this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=048c85c7f5aa82f5a534bfb6569552b0

Comment: I also updated the question with expected sample result

Comment: welp in DEMO your datarow in tblChild is (1,'...', 2, 2, 1) , if you correct the datarow and the output is the expected result.

Comment: But it means, id, note, parent1Id, parent2Id and parent3Id

Comment: do you realize that this row should be (1,'...', 1, 2, 1)... [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d9acfc0d1d81029404c691cbbfba057)

Comment: that DEMO get the same result as what you expect @hikhyper

Comment: wow. so it actually solves the problem right? I just needed to use `t1` instead of `p1` and `p2`

Comment: @hikhyper yep. you just need to look into how `join` work,check msdn for better info. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you thank you for the help and link. I'll try this same concept in my mysql queries. Stay safe!